# Program that finds tables' distance

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double dtw(int ,int ,double*,double*);

int main(void){
    int iG,jG,i,j;

    double dtwtemp;
    printf("give the 1st size : ");
    scanf("%d",&iG);
    printf("\n");
    printf("give the 2st size : ");
    scanf("%d",&jG);
    printf("\n");

    double *a=malloc(iG*sizeof(double));
    double *b=malloc(jG*sizeof(double));

    for(i=0;i<iG;i++){
        printf("give %d number of first table ",i+1);
        scanf("%lf",&a[i]);
        printf("\n");
        }
        printf("----------------\n");
    for(j=0;j<jG;j++){
        printf("give %d number of second table ",j+1);
        scanf("%lf",&b[j]);
        printf("\n");
        }
    for(i=0;i<iG;i++){
        printf("%.2f    ",a[i]);}
        printf("\n");
    for(j=0;j<jG;j++){
        printf("%.2f    ",b[j]);}

    dtw(i,j, &a , &b ); 

}


double dtw(int i ,int j ,double *a ,double *b){

    double dtwmin,dtwtemp;

    dtwtemp=(a[i]-b[j])*(a[i]-b[j]);

    if (i>1){
        if (j>1){
            dtwmin=dtw( i,j,&a[(i-1)],&b[j]);
            if (dtwmin>dtw(i,j,&a[i],&b[(j-1)]))
                dtwmin=dtw(i,j,&a[i],&b[(j-1)]);
            if (dtwmin>dtw(i,j,&a[(i-1)],&b[(j-1)]))
                dtwmin=dtw(i,j,&a[(i-1)],&b[(j-1)]);
        }
        else
            dtwmin=dtw(i,j,&a[(i-1)],&b[1]);    
    }
    else{
        if (j>1)
            dtwmin=dtw(i,j,&a[1],&b[(j-1)]);
        else
            dtwmin=dtw(i,j,&a[1],&b[1]);
}
return dtwtemp+dtwmin ;}
```

Can somebody help please cause it shows segmentation fault and I don't know what is going on.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

In main, when you call dtw i and j are equal to iG and jG respectively, and are out of bounds for the arrays.

Comment: so what exactly should i do?

Comment: If you set i=iG-1 and j=jG-1 just before the dtw call, you should not get a segfault.

Comment: Change `dtw(i,j, &a , &b );` to `dtw(i,j, a , b );`. a and b are already double pointers. When you ask for their adress, you get a pointer of a pointer. Im a bit surprised that this wasnt raised by the compiler.

Comment: One last thing that should not be related to the segfault, in dtw you seem to asume that the first element of a c array is [1] when it is actually [0]

Comment: Finally change the expressions like `&a[(i-1)]` to `a+(i-1)`

Comment: i hope you meant to change every table format to pointer! cause thats what i did and still not working...

Comment: No, I did not mean to change the table format to pointers. I'm sorry that I was not clear with my last comment. I meant that in the `dtw` function you should change the statements like `dtwmin>dtw(i,j,&a[i],&b[(j-1)])` to `dtwmin>dtw(i,j,a+i,b+j-1)`.

Comment: Actually, the final weird thing with your code is that when you call `dtw` from inside `dtw`, for instance `dtwmin=dtw( i,j,&a[(i-1)],&b[j]);`, you should change the arguments `i` and `j` to match the array's `a` and `b` indeces. What I mean is that you should call `dtw` like `dtwmin=dtw( i-1,j,&a[(i-1)],&b[j]);`. If you don't do so, you will enter an infinite recursion. Maybe that is what is causing your segfault.